# How to get the all position from Gridview that I have check?

Tags: android, gridview, position

I use Fragment which  `extends Fragment implements MultiChoiceModeListener`.

And a `class extends BaseAdapter`.

I can get the only position When I select the item from Gridview like the following code:

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mActionText.setText(formatString(fileListView.getCheckedItemCount()));

    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    Log.i(TAG, "fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions(); = " + checkedItems);
    if (checkedItems != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
                String item = fileListView.getAdapter().getItem(
                                      checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
                Log.i(TAG,item + " was selected");
            }
        }
    }
    mode.invalidate();

    }
```

And the value is like the following log:

```
EG Player(21867): fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions(); = android.util.SparseBooleanArray@43625dc0
I/MJPEG Player(21867): tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.FileBrowser.Model.FileNode@43c4b7e8 was selected
```

What is the value of item mean ?

Does there has other method can get all the item that I have select from Gridview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridView` element allows you to get the checked views like so, depending on what you need:

```
gridView.getCheckedItemIds();
gridView.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

Comment: I have try to use getCheckedItemPositions();. But I don't know how to turn it to position

Comment: @MartinWun it's a `SparseBooleanArray`, check out how it works here: http://ktatsiu.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/learning-android-how-to-use-getcheckeditempositions-of-listview/